# When do I have to close mysqli (Database) connection?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

For now, I have one connect.php file e.g.

```
$mysql_host = "";
$mysql_database = "";
$mysql_user = "";
$mysql_password = "";

$con = new mysqli(
    $mysql_host,
    $mysql_user,
    $mysql_password,
    $mysql_database
);

// Check connection
if ($con->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $con->connect_error);
}
```

In every other PHP file that uses MySQL queries, I use "include 'connect.php';"

For Instance on W3Schools, they create for every query a new connection and then close it after use. See here: [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp): I'm not sure if they do it just for showing purpose, or if it is best practice to do it this way.

Do I have to close the connection after each selection and then establish a new one, for the next query? If not, when do I finally have to close the connection? On the end of the PHP File with all the queries?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A quote from the php.net site.

> Open non-persistent MySQL connections and result sets are automatically closed when their objects are destroyed. Explicitly closing open connections and freeing result sets is optional. However, it's a good idea to close the connection as soon as the script finishes performing all of its database operations, if it still has a lot of processing to do after getting the results.

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.close.php

Answer (score 2):

Close the connection when you are done using it for that page.  If you have, say, a blog, the button that you use to post it would start the code that would open the connection, do some work with the connection (like adding it to your db and or showing it on a page) and then it would close the connection so that it isn't open any longer than it needs.  But when you click the button again it would start the process over, only using resources as it needs them.

Answer (score -3):

Best practice is to use close function in footer.php

Comment: Not sure about that. If you are done with SQL in header.php, then you should close SQL then.

Comment: Then you need to write mysqli_close() again and again in each file. Rather put it in 'footer file'.

Comment: As @Thais already mentioned, PHP automatically destroys open connections at the end of the script execution. So closing mysql at the very end of your script is a little redundant. Closing your connection allows for your resources to be reallocated.