# many mysqli connections with close?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a php that I need to many selects, like 10, so I do:

```
$stmt = $mysqli_->prepare("SELECT count(id) as num FROM table WHERE id=?");
$stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($count);
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close();

$stmt = $mysqli_->prepare("SELECT count(id) as num FROM table2 WHERE id=?");
$stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($count2);
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close();

$stmt = $mysqli_->prepare("SELECT count(id) as num FROM table3 WHERE id=?");
$stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($count3);
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close();

...
```

is it ok to use the `$stmt->close();` all the time or would it kill the connection performance?

Comment: "is it ok to use the $stmt->close(); all the time". Yes. "would it kill the connection performance?". Somewhat. If you need 10 separate queries, it might be useful to figure out a way to lower that amount. Either change the database or your code. Or don't if this works fine and quickly, all up to you :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When do I have to close mysqli (Database) connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29437105/when-do-i-have-to-close-mysqli-database-connection)

Comment: @MohammedYassineCHABLI I don't ask if I have to close the connection. I asked if closing all the time is ok, like in my case, or if I have another way re-use an already openning connection.

Comment: Why not using UNION? single query in multiple tables and single close might be better in this case.

Comment: @Noman maybe I can use union in some. but my example is simple, I think in the most of them I have different number of fields.